# could someone help explain how this indexOf() implementation works?

Tags: java, linked-list

This is a sample implementation of `indexOf()` in `LinkedList` on Oracle's website. I'm a little confused on how the `if` loop works here:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))
            return it.previousIndex();
    // Element not found
    return -1;
}
```

So the `ListIterator` object is created at the head of the list. `for` loop goes on until the iterator reaches the list's end, and the `if` loop checks if the target object is found. The part I did not understand though, is that why does the `if` loop check `it.next() == null` when `e == null`? Could someone help walk me through how it's done when input e is null?

Comment: it would return -1 if the list doesn't contain any null reference. Rembember the for-loop only runs as long as it.hasNext().

Comment: @FlorianMinges what does it mean by the list doesn't contain any null reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop checks if `it.next() == null` only if `e == null` this is done to avoid NullPointerException when evaluating `e.equals(it.next())`.

if `e != null`, then the regular `e.equals()` method is invoked.

`null` is a valid "element" that can be inserted to a `LinkedList`, so this must be taken into consideration.

The position of the last element is not inserted. Note that unlike the text book data structure where the last element in a Linked List is `null`, in here - when you get to the last element - `it.hasNext()` will be evaluated to false, without letting you see this "junk" element.

Comment: oh I didn't know a list can have null elements... that makes so much sense. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `e` is `null`, the `indexOf()` method will iterate until it finds another `null` element in the iterable object you have passed and return its index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what is going on with regards to the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java).

This line:

```
if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))
```

Checks to see that **e is null**, if it is, then it will check that the **iterator's next element is null** (this effectively stops the iteration operation so as to avoid a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)), otherwise: (if e is **not null** - i.e. it has some value in it), perform the comparison:

```
e.equals(it.next())
```

Comment: if `e` is `null`, it will not set the iterator to `null` - it will check if the iterators next element is `null`.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianMinges, I have updated my answer as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))` - this is a java ternary operator

`it.next() == null` is a null check(returning true or false to see if this is the last element)
if that is true

`return it.previousIndex();` executes

if e is not null, then

`e.equals(it.next())`

executes and if thats true,

`return it.previousIndex();` executes

which is the index of the element your want the index of. Hope my explanation isn't confusing.

Comment: `==` is an equality operator in java, whereas `=` is used to assign values to variables. Therefore `it.next() == null` is a check, and not an assignment. Besides, it wouldn't make sense to have an assignment in an if-loop (your code wouldn't compile), since you want a boolean statement there.